# How can I Set a end time value to a video played on a browser using HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a video which is around 50secs in length. I want that only the first 30secs of the video to be played. I have created a HTML code which renders the video on a webpage but it plays all the 50secs. I want only the first 30secs to be played.

Comment: Use `stop` at `30s` mark. Or use external program and cut only 30s of video

Answer (score 4):

Reference [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

Specifying playback range

> When specifying the URI of media for an  or  element,
>   you can optionally include additional information to specify the
>   portion of the media to play. To do this, append a hash mark ("#")
>   followed by the media fragment description.

A time range is specified using the syntax:

```
#t=[starttime][,endtime]
```

The time can be specified as a number of seconds (as a floating-point value) or as an hours/minutes/seconds time separated with colons (such as 2:05:01 for 2 hours, 5 minutes, and 1 second).

A few examples:

```
http://example.com/video.ogv#t=10,20
```

Specifies that the video should play the range 10 seconds through 20 seconds.

```
http://example.com/video.ogv#t=,10.5
```

Specifies that the video should play from the beginning through 10.5 seconds.

```
http://example.com/video.ogv#t=,02:00:00
```

Specifies that the video should play from the beginning through two hours.

```
http://example.com/video.ogv#t=60
```

Specifies that the video should start playing at 60 seconds and play through the end of the video.

Answer (score 2):

here's the code that will only play the first maxTime seconds and then pause

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.play();
var maxTime = 10;
video.addEventListener("progress", function(){
  if(video.currentTime >= maxTime){
    video.pause();  
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<video id='video'
      preload='none'
      poster="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">

      <source id='mp4'
        src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"
        type='video/mp4'>
      <source id='webm'
        src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm"
        type='video/webm'>
      <source id='ogv'
        src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"
        type='video/ogg'>

      <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
```